# Noise Suppression in Mic

Tags: sound, microphone

I'm just a new ubuntu user. And I have the following question or maybe idea for future implementation.

So here is a feature that I have in windows that makes my skype calls much easier.

[image]

So what I'm asking is if a comparable feature like this on the picture exists.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no master control for echo-cancellation or noise suppression in Ubuntu, but if you use empathy as your chat client, it has an option to enable echo cancellation. You can find it by navigating to Empathy>>preferences>>calls>>

Skype has an automatic noise cancellation/echo cancellation function, so those calls should also not be a problem.  If you could post specific outcomes you wish to achieve with this, more people might be able to contribute. What kind of applications do you hope to use? What is the likely source of echo or noise? etc

Comment: I'd only like to stress that noise reduction is a software feature.  The operating system and it's drivers are responsible for delivering the signals (sounds) from the mic to any software requesting them.  The software writers then code to "drop" wave patterns which seem like noise.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to communicate. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Echo cancellation in Ubuntu [can be done](http://arunraghavan.net/2011/08/hello-hello-hello/) by running:

```
pactl load-module module-echo-cancel
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is basically the same as Echo cancellation in telephony.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+echo+cancellation is simple introduction. Also have a look at the pages for the mark and mark2 echo canceller there and the mentioned TI application note.

Also this site: http://www.embeddedstar.com/articles/2003/7/article20030720-1.html explains the mechanics quite well.

You'll have to intercept both the music player's output and the microphone input, and then pass the samples via some sort of IPC into your DSP process. JACK actually does this, but setting things up (e.g. ALSA->JACK bridge, if your music player and/or Skype does not natively support JACK as sound interface) does require some skill.

I guess it could work fairly well, but it probably requires quite some CPU. Especially XRUNS (audio buffer under- or overrun) can be really bad for your echo canceller, i.e. you might need realtime linux kernel patches. Implementation is not trivial, either. Also having stereo sound from your music player will reduce your cancellation success.
SOURCE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875818/software-sound-cancelling-destructive-interference-tools-on-linux