# mic off white noise

Tags: sound, alsa, 22.04, jack

Hi I have mic + mixer + jack and xlr; and when I off the mic I have white noise, and when I on the mic I have an electronic noise. Do you know how to solved that ? I found only this topic : [Noise Suppression in Mic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230316/noise-suppression-in-mic)

```
lspci | grep Audio 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)

cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xef120000 irq 133

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
Codec: Intel Skylake HDMI

alsactl -v
alsactl version 1.2.6
```

Does I Need to buy a new sound card ?

Sound like that : https://vocaroo.com/13lsNIHuahrE

Comment: I try with alsamixer , to down PCM volume and Front (but the mic is plugged on the back) . https://postimg.cc/hzXPtByH

Answer (score 0):

the pcm and the front automatically return to 100%, when I go down in the green pcm and front there is no more white noise and electronic noise.

[image: alsamixer settings]

and when I want to use my speaker I can't choose on my setting (say " simultaneous output " ):

[image: speaker settings screenshot]

for settings of alsamixer I try to change my .conf like this : [Alsamixer or Pulseaudio reverts PCM channel level to 100% in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628215/alsamixer-or-pulseaudio-reverts-pcm-channel-level-to-100-in-14-04)

```
[Element PCM] volume = merge
```

to

```
[Element PCM]
volume = ignore
```

But Now I can't select my speakers on pulseaudio panel settings.

maybe it comes from the capture, I lowered the volume

[image: capture]